# Deployment of Rails 3 App using Bundler and Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler

During capistrano deployment of a Rails3 app, I want my server to install gems, using Gemfile.lock, every time I deploy. And since my server does not have rvm and all.. All gems should be installed as system gems.

To install system gems, we need to put `sudo gem install anygem` or for bunder, we need to give command `sudo bundle install` inside our `current` directory of capistrano deployment structure.

Everytime, I deploy, my deployment breaks at the gems installation process. I need `sudo bundle install` to run. For that, I need a deployment hook for capistrano. The prebuilt ones that are supplied by bundler gem itself is not working for me. My confusion boils down to these three questions.

1. When should I invoke the `sudo bundle install` command in the deployment process - i mean after which capistrano task ?
2. For running `sudo` commands using capistrano, what declarations I should specify in my cap file ? Note - i already have pushed my public key as authorized keys in my server.
3. How should the bundle install hook be written in the `cap` file ?

Please help.

Comment: strongly recommend you use rvm in production, it removes all the sudo mess

Comment: @SamSaffron, with gems - yes. But if you use god, you're back to sudo mess. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `bundle install --deployment` you shouldn't need sudo access as the gems should be installed to vendor/bundle in your app rather than to the system itself.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `require "bundler/capistrano"` to your `deploy.rb` *should* just work. It should declare a folder to install gems to that do not require sudo access, regardless of rvm.

Is that still failing for you?

Answer (score 0):

i use that in my deploy.rb:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
... deploy recipe

namespace :bundle do
  desc "Install bundles into application"
  task :install, :roles => [:app] do
    run "cd #{current_path} && LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' bundle install --deployment --without test"
  end
end
```

Then after normal deploy i run "cap bundle:install"

note: Using UTF-8 to prevent ruby1.9 ASCII chars problems.